# `sh` access denied over ssh connection

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, cygwin, sh

I have an ubuntu server and a windows XP client running Cygwin. The server `ssh`'s into the client and tries to execute a shell script with some params, with the following command:

```
ssh user@IP_ADDR 'sh /home/user/project/clientside 2 5 7 6 9 5 7 IP_ADDR'
```

where `IP_ADDR` is the IP address of client.
However, while doing so, I get the following error:

```
Access is denied.
```

Thinking this might be a user permissions error, I tried running `sh /home/user/project/clientside 2 5 7 6 9 5 7 IP_ADDR` on the client, on Cygwin, while logged in as `user`.
This works as expected.

Then I thought that this might be an error with the login that I use when I ssh into the client. So I executed this instead:

```
ssh user@IP_ADDR 'whoami'
```

and got back `user`.

This happened even after I did `chmod -R 777 /home/user/project` on the client, in Cygwin.

For kicks, I got on Cygwin on the client and did `ssh localhost` and manually executed `sh /home/user/project/clientside 2 5 7 6 9 5 7 IP_ADDR`.
This worked as expected.

However, when I did `ssh IP_ADDR` from Cygwin and did `ssh localhost` and manually executed `sh /home/user/project/clientside 2 5 7 6 9 5 7 IP_ADDR`, I get the same `Access is denied.` error.

Why is this happening? How can I fix this?

By the way, both the server and the client have each other's rsa public key for passwordless ssh

Comment: Can you post your `client` Cygwin /var/log/auth.log. Look for error related to the problem.

Comment: I got the correct solution - check out my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with they way windows services work.
This fixes the problem:

1. Close Cygwin
2. Go to windows services (`services.msc` on `Run Dialog`).
3. Stop the `CYGWIN sshd` service
4. Double click on `CYGWIN sshd` to enter the service properties
5. Stop the service
6. Under the `Log On` tab, ensure that `Log on as` is set to `Local System account` and `Allow service to interact with desktop` is checked
7. Restart the service
8. Restart Cygwin
9. Go get a beer

Comment: hmm....doesn't the cygwin ssh setup program do this for you?

Comment: apparently it didn't do it for me - I had to do this on >=4 computers, and all of them needed this fix

Answer (score 1):

You can try `ssh IP_ADDR sh echo lalala`  to just that indeed you can open an sh terminal.
if it fails ... you know the reason. Also it would be helpful to give us a sample of /var/log/messages and /var/log/secure {or whatever log you think that will be useful}

Comment: That's an interesting idea. I get `/bin/echo: /bin/echo: cannot execute binary file` when I attempt `ssh user@IP_ADDR 'sh echo lala'`

Comment: I get this error despite the fact that `/bin/echo.exe` has `755` permissions